# Solve 2 equations in 2 unknowns in octave?

Tags: systems-of-equations, matlab, octave

I have the following 2 equations in 2 unknowns $(x,t)$:

$(t*x-20)^4 = 100*((t*x-20)^2-t^2(150^2-x^2)) $

$(t*\sqrt{(150^2-x^2)}+70) = ((t*x)+30)*tan(arctan(7/3)+36*t)$

I tried solving them using [octave online](https://octave-online.net) using the following code:

```
syms x t  
[X, Y] = solve(((t*x)-20)^4 == 100*(((t*x)-20)^2-(t^2)*(150^2-x^2)), (t*sqrt((150^2)-x^2) + 70) == ((t*x) + 30)*tan(atan(7/3) + 36*t), x, t)
```

but unfortunately the following error occurred:

> **warning**: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous, see "help
>   sym"
>
> **warning**: called from
>       double_to_sym_heuristic at line 50 column 7
>       sym at line 373 column 13
>       plus at line 63 column 5
>
> **error**: Python exception: PolynomialError: x**(-10) contains an element
>   of the generators set
>       occurred at line 21 of the Python code block:
>       d = sp.solve(eqs, *symbols, set=True)
>
> **error**: called from
>       python_cmd at line 179 column 7
>       solve at line 176 column 9

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For sure the assingment "==" that you make is not accepted. Write your system as $F(x,t)=0$. In this way, the first equation becomes $(t*sqrt((150^2)-x^2) + 70) - ((t*x) + 30)*tan(atan(7/3) + 36*t)$ and do the same for the other equation. 
A best thing to do would be to use Newton's method, but if you're lazy and don't want to compute the Jacobian matrix...

Comment: @VoB i have modified it to be :   [X, Y] = solve(((t*x)-20)^4 - 100*(((t*x)-20)^2-(t^2)*(150^2-x^2)) == 0, (t*sqrt((150^2)-x^2) + 70) - ((t*x) + 30)*tan(atan(7/3) + 36*t) == 0, x, t),  but it gave me the same error

Comment: The problem is in $==0$. You don't have to write it. The solve command receives just the expression of the function that you have to set to $0$. Do you know how Newton's method (for non-linear systems) works?

Comment: @VoB you mean to put it in form of :  [X, Y] = solve(f1(x,t),f2(x,t), x, t)

Comment: With **Maple** I have: `[{t = 0.08434874022, x = 139.4157757}, {t = 0.1681041901, x = 147.8592665},
    {t = -0.1832921530, x = -147.4989473},
    {t = -0.09222376907, x = -139.8601075}]`

Comment: @Ahmed yes, where $f_1(x,t)$ is: $(t \sqrt((150^2)-x^2) + 70) - ((tx) + 30)*\tan(\arctan(7/3) + 36t)$

Comment: @VoB i have modified them and octave gave me the following error:   warning: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous, see "help sym"
warning: called from
    double_to_sym_heuristic at line 50 column 7
    sym at line 373 column 13
    plus at line 63 column 5
error: Python exception: PolynomialError: x**(-10) contains an element of the generators set
    occurred at line 21 of the Python code block:
    d = sp.solve(eqs, *symbols, set=True)
error: called from
    python_cmd at line 179 column

Comment: @VoB it is better ,if you would not mind, to try it your self on the given online octave site

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk it is online or offline program? would you mind providing the solution code

Comment: Maple is offline program.Code:`eq1 := [(t*x - 20)^4 - 100*(t*x - 20)^2 + 100*t^2*(-x^2 + 22500) = 0,
    t*sqrt(-x^2 + 22500) + 70 - (x*t + 30)*tan(arctan(7/3) + 36*t) = 0];f := (a, b) -> fsolve(eq1, {t = a, x = b});
[f(0.08, 140), f(0.16, 142), f(-0.16, 142), f(-0.077, -143)];` **a** and **b** are starting values for the variables for `fsolve`.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk what if the equations have the following forms:    [X, Y] = solve(((t*v_x) + x_s-h)^4 - (a^2)*(((t*v_x) + x_s-h)^2 - (t^2)*(v^2-v_x^2)), (t*sqrt((v^2)-v_x^2) + y_s) - ((t*v_x) + x_s)*tan(atan(y_s/x_s) + w*t), v_x, t)   where syms x_s y_s v v_x t a h w are symbols and we are solving for (t and v_x).. what is the solution in this case